# .on()-Function does not rebuild DOM

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, scroll

I am trying to automatically click a link when I scroll down to the bottom. It then loads some content with another link that does the same. This works perfectly for the first time but when the next link is loaded via AJAX it does not get clicked anymore. I assume it has something to do with the DOM not getting rebuild. Thank you.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {         
       timeout = window.setTimeout( check, 100);
    });

function check(){
    if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= ($('body').height() * 0.9)) {
        alert('Call me!');
        $('.selector').click(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: try with ``$('.selector').trigger("click");``

Comment: Do you realize that once this code finds an object that matches the selector, this code is going to be executing the `.click()` method every 100ms.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - `.click()` is already a shortcut for `.trigger( "click" )`.  Explained right in the [jQuery doc for `.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).  No need to change that part.

Comment: Perhaps expand on what you're actually doing because the isolated given code works. The question  mentions the dom getting rebuilt. It's not in the code given.

Comment: Thank you so much already. Yes, the code works for the first link at the bottom of the page. The click on the link by the script works when you scroll down at the bottom. Per AJAX it then loads the next content with another link to click at the bottom. This link is not clicked anymore by the script. It can be clicked manually and works then as it should. This is why I assumed the DOM is the problem.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - implementing your solution had no effect. So I assume jfriend00 is right. Thank you though!