# jQuery doesn't fire twice after call to .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to change the content of a div `(#mydiv)` via `AJAX`.

To do that I create a button `(#change-button)` inside `#mydiv` that trigger the following `jQuery` script

```
$(#change-button).on("click", function(){

    $("#mydiv").load("page_to_be_loaded.hmtml #mydiv");
});
```

Basically I replace the text in #mydiv with the new page's one.
This code works fine for the first time, but if I click again on the freshly loaded `#change-button jQuery` doesn't fire anymore.

I understand the theory: the new `#mydiv` that has been injected by `.load()` is not seen by the `DOM`, so the `jQuery` script doesn't work.

I found at least two similar questions on SO, but none was properly answered and overall none seems to solve my problem. Can anyone explaining clearly the best practice in these cases.

Here is the other questions:

[Update DOM after insert in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550761/update-dom-after-insert-in-jquery)

[.on()-Function does not rebuild DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874187/on-function-does-not-rebuild-dom)

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure but try creating a button outside #mydiv.
<br/>In ref to "To do that I create a button (#change-button) inside #mydiv"

Comment: FYI: I think that you've also misspelled 'html' in the `load` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use delegation like this:

```
$("body").on("click","#change-button", function(){
    $("#mydiv").load("page_to_be_loaded.hmtml #mydiv");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is because y our contents are dynamically loaded, so they are not present at the time of event binding. That's why it's not firing.

You can use delegation like bellow

```
$(document).on("click",'#change-button',function(){})
```